# How set a parameter type as inout when using rpc with gwt?

Tags: service, rpc, out, param, gwt2

I've a sample gwt2 rpc service & i need to set some of it's parameters as out or inout (like out or ref parameter types in microsoft wcf), but i could not find anything about it in gwt documents or related forums :(
Can anybody help me please ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that gwt rpc services can't contain any out or inout parameter(even if you use java arrays as method parameters, the data binding would be only one way).
In order to returning more than one value from your methods, you can simply return some complex serializable data structure from your service method(Hashmap or ListArray are good choices)